# classpath issue with intellij run configurations using gradle & idea-ext plugin

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

I'm using `org.jetbrains.gradle.plugin.idea-ext` to define an idea run configuration.
In my case I have several java modules loaded by the `java.util.ServiceLoader`.

Then I have a separate dummy module without any code, just to define a classpath including all plugins.

I prepared a sample project to demonstrate my observations:

https://github.com/dieterstueken/java-plugins

If I run the configuration using Intellij, with `delegateBuildRunToGradle = false`, it works as expected.

Delegating it to gradle insted, the extended classpath is not used. Seems gradle uses the classpath of the main class, only.

Answer (score 0):

I took a deep debug dive into the Intellij source code and created an issue about at:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-332412

So, the discussion will continue over there.